# Adding jQuery event handlers to elements with wildcard IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following in a document.ready block:

```
        $("[id^=summaryDetailLink_]").each(function(index) {
        var splitID = this.id.split("_");
        this.click(alert('clicked: '+splitID[1])); //toggleDetail(splitID[1])
    });
```

Ultimately I want to detect when a TD with an ID of "summaryDetail_" is clicked on and fire the toggleDetail function with the ID taken from the TD.ID attribute.

The above seems to generate the correct ID (the alert popsup) but is firing when the page loads rather than when I click on the element.

So problem number 1 - why is it firing on page load rather than creating a handler for click on each element and waiting for that click?

Problem number 2, in reading around this issue it seems it would be more sensible to create a single event handler on the table rather the TD then determine which TD element was clicked. How would I convert the code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to first question:

```
$(function() {
    $("[id^=summaryDetailLink_]").click(function() {
        var splitID = $(this).id.split("_");
        alert('clicked: '+splitID[1])
    });
}
```

Answer to second question, you can do this:

```
$('table#yourtable').on('click', '[id^=summaryDetailLink_]', function(e) {
    var splitID = $(this).id.split("_");
    alert('clicked: '+splitID[1])
});
```

Comment: After changing "$(this)" to just "this" in the code it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding how the click handler works:

```
$(function() {
    $("[id^=summaryDetailLink_]").click(function() {
        var splitID = $(this).id.split("_");
        alert('clicked: '+splitID[1])
    });
}
```